# How to change the location of twirl templates for integration tests?

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, typesafe-stack, twirl

I'm trying to use [**twirl**](https://github.com/spray/twirl) as part of my integration tests.

My integration tests have an HTTP simplicator that mimics a real world service. To implement this simplicator in the tests, I'm using [spray-can](https://github.com/spray/spray-can) embedded HTTP server which needs to spit out responses based on **twirl** templates.

My tests are located at `/src/it/scala` so naturally I want to place these twirl templates inside `/src/it/twirl`. This doesn't work since the twirl compiler ignores this directory.

If I place the twirl templates in `/src/main/twirl`, everything works fine - but I'm trying to avoid this because I don't want these templates to clutter the production package (the templates only come into play in the tests so they should only compile inside when the tests are run).

How can I tell the twirl compiler to look for templates in the new directory?

Comment: Could you provide your build definition?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using `sourceDirectory in twirlCompile` that [by default](https://github.com/spray/twirl/blob/master/sbt-twirl/src/main/scala/twirl/sbt/TwirlPlugin.scala#L36) is set to:

```
sourceDirectory in twirlCompile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile) / "twirl"
```

Redefine the `sourceDirectory` setting for the `twirlCompile` task for the `IntegrationTest` config. The following *should* work (it's yet to be verified).

```
sourceDirectory in twirlCompile in IntegrationTest := (sourceDirectory in IntegrationTest).value / "twirl"
```

Comment: How can we access twirlCompile?

Comment: You have to install the sbt plugin to have `twirlCompile` scope available.